# How to make an exception for <meta name="robots" content="nofollow"> for several links?

Tags: html, seo, nofollow

I have many pages with 60+ links to have a meta tag:

```
<meta name="robots" content="nofollow">
```

And several links (1-3 per page) on these pages, that should have an attribute "follow" for robots.
I read that the use this construction with the above one will have no effect:

```
<a href="http://example.com/needed_to_follow_link.html" rel="follow">
```

Is it possible to set an exception for those links without changing meta tag to **"follow"** and adding for each of 60+ links attribute **rel="nofollow"**?

Answer (score 0):

No, that’s not possible (unless you want to use "hacks", like using an `iframe` for the part that contains the links that should not fall under `nofollow`).

By definition, meta tags (i.e., `meta` elements with the `name` attribute) apply to the whole document.

If there were a `follow` (or similar) link type, it *could* be defined to overwrite the document-wide `nofollow` from the `meta`-`robots` element. But such a link type doesn’t exist ([see registry](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions)).